# Software for polar-coordinate plots

Tags: software-recommendation, csv, plot

I'm looking for easy software which can create 3d plot with polar coordinates (cylindrical coordinates) from a csv file (or pasted from eg. libre office). Making a trend-surface or sth like it would be useful too. I want also to have only 90 degree view.

Comment: "easy" is subjective.

Comment: I suspect this is too specific for there to be a dedicated piece of software (although I wouldn't say for sure there isn't). Likely your best bet is one of the numerical computing packages - eg R, ipython, octave, gnuplot, ROOT.

Comment: I am currently trying gnuplot, but i thought ther will be sth easier (I mean it is not hard, but i dont have much time to do this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of the answer depend which kind of interface you want and the kind of output you require (quality, details, etc).

If you are OK with a command line interface, the "classical"  package for doing that is `gnuplot`, as stated in the comments. This is what I normally use for the first shot. I however think that [PyXplot](http://pyxplot.org.uk/) will normally give much nicer plots (but it is a bit more difficult to grok, and to really use it you have to know LaTeX).

For an example of use of spherical/cylindrical coordinates in gnuplot, see for example this page: http://www.gnuplot.info/demo/world.html --- the trick here is the `set mapping` command. You could need to do some transformation on your input file, however. [This article by Lee Phillips](http://www.packtpub.com/article/3d-plot-using-gnuplot) seems interesting, too.

```
gnuplot> help set mapping
 If data are provided to `splot` in spherical or cylindrical coordinates,
 the `set mapping` command should be used to instruct `gnuplot` how to
 interpret them.

 Syntax:
       set mapping {cartesian | spherical | cylindrical}

 A cartesian coordinate system is used by default.

 For a spherical coordinate system, the data occupy two or three columns
 (or `using` entries).  The first two are interpreted as the azimuthal
 and polar angles theta and phi (or "longitude" and "latitude"), in the
 units specified by `set angles`.  The radius r is taken from the third
 column if there is one, or is set to unity if there is no third column.
 The mapping is:

       x = r * cos(theta) * cos(phi)
       y = r * sin(theta) * cos(phi)
       z = r * sin(phi)

 Note that this is a "geographic" spherical system, rather than a "polar"
 one (that is, phi is measured from the equator, rather than the pole).
Press return for more: 

 For a cylindrical coordinate system, the data again occupy two or three
 columns.  The first two are interpreted as theta (in the units specified by
 `set angles`) and z.  The radius is either taken from the third column or set
 to unity, as in the spherical case.  The mapping is:

       x = r * cos(theta)
       y = r * sin(theta)
       z = z

 The effects of `mapping` can be duplicated with the `using` filter on the
 `splot` command, but `mapping` may be more convenient if many data files are
 to be processed.  However even if `mapping` is used, `using` may still be
 necessary if the data in the file are not in the required order.
```

If you are looking for more graphical things, [this Wikipedia page can help you](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_graphing_software). In the end I found that command-line driven programs are better for this kind of things (hated Origin with all my forces), but your mileage may vary.

[QtiPlot](http://soft.proindependent.com/qtiplot.html), in particular, seems a nicely done program; it is open-source and free on Linux (you can install it simply with `apt-get install qtiplot`):

[image]

but I never used it in extended way so I can't help with it a lot. 
...But if you really like it remember that it is [donation-ware](http://soft.proindependent.com/why_donate.html)(1) :-)

(1) I am NOT related at all to this project or the developers. I simply checked it and find it quite well done and well maintained.

Comment: I dont see there in Qti option of "polar/cylindrical coordinates"

Comment: Never use that to do such a thing --- maybe http://soft.proindependent.com/doc/manual-en/x4568.html#add-function-dialog-3 can help.

Comment: but it's for functions and i have a csv file with data

Comment: I've decided to use gnuplot, thx for help